# Memory exhausted trying to extract from big mcmc.list

Tags: r, winbugs, jags, r-coda

I have problem trying to extract a single variable from big `mcmc.list`:

```
> x <- outRJ$mcmc[,'avail_int']
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 146.8 Mb
```

The `outRJ$mcmc` mcmc.list is big, 442 MB actually (contains data for 3 chains for like 960 variables, each 20000 iterations):

```
> object.size(outRJ$mcmc)/1024/1024
[1] 442.5508 #
```

But the single variable should have like 234 kB only! But the extraction of it seems to require much much more memory!

#### How can I extract from a big mcmc.list without requiring too much memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current subsetting code (in the function [.mcmc.list) is making a copy of each element of the list before subsetting it. I have modified the code in the development version of coda. In the meantime, Matt's workaround should do because it also avoids the redundant copy.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
 x <- as.mcmc.list(lapply(outRJ$mcmc, function(x) return(x[,'avail_int',drop=FALSE])))
```

Matt